# How to bind model from both the request body and URL

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-binding

Our API endpoints typically demand a timestamp. For certain endpoints, the timestamp is expected in the request body, while the other parameters are expected in the URI. For example, a delete request would look something like this:

```
DELETE http://example.com/Foos/1
{ 'timestamp': '28/05/2014T12:45:23' }
```

Given that Web API will not bind from both the URI and request body out of the box, we are having to pull the timestamp out of the request in the controller - yuk!

Has anyone come across a means of binding from both the body and the URI?

Is our approach to deleting with a timestamp considered RESTful? (we think so). If not, what would be a more RESTful approach?

Comment: Just out of curiocity - Why are you sending timestamp, can't you generate that on server and user server's time stamp instead.

Comment: We use the timestamp to determine the intended order of multiple requests.